# Feasibility of using ROS for commercial products

Tags: ros, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have a question about the feasibility of using ROS in (not so big) commercial products. We have developed a working prototype of a mobile robot that needs to run SLAM - we are using gmapping here - and has to drive around based on the inputs from some Infrared sensors, and such. “Sorry if i can’t disclose any more details here.”

now we want to go ahead with commercialising the product but right now we have a couple of computers that run ROS and its packages that we developed in order to properly work the Robot.

My question is do we HAVE TO put a computer (e.g SBC) inside our commercial product in order to use our current ROS based softwares? or is there another way to adopt or cross compile our current ROS based softwares / architecture so it can be put into an embedded board for the production units? Or what is your suggestion about what we can do with our ros based system that we have now for our purpose?

Thank you and regards.

Steve J.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219178/feasibility-of-using-ros-for-commercial-products/) by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-10-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Putting an SBC onto your robot will be by far the easiest.

There is a community using yocto to create images for different embedded targets. There are instructions for [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded) the title page says hydro but it's also linked to from the [indigo install page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation) so should work for indigo too.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*"We have developed a working prototype of a mobile robot that needs to run SLAM - we are using gmapping here -"* I don't think you can use `gmapping` unfortunately. It's licensed under the Creative Commons (Attribution-**NonCommercial**-ShareAlike). Take a look at `slam_karto` and `hector_slam`.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1